# How to define properties conditionally according to the conditional types for typescript interfaces

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have an existing typescript interface used in a codebase

```
interface example<condition extends true | false = false> {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: condition extends true ? string : number;
  // many other properties
}
```

Now I want to keep property **a** if condition is true, but replace property **a** with property **d** if condition is false, how can I do it?

Are there any easy ways like how javascript object can do with it like the following (has syntax error though)

```
interface example<condition extends true | false = false> {
  ...(condition extends true && {a: string});
  ...(condition extends false && {d: string});
  b: string;
  c: condition extends true ? string : number;
  // many other properties
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next type:

```js
type Example<Condition extends boolean = false> = Condition extends true ? {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
} : {
    d: string;
    b: string;
    c: number;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQDwGED2A7AEwEtgj8oI5gJCBnKAIxx3QTygF4oAzBVWiAD5OUXIRJl2lanSjAATgFdoAfigBvAFBQdUBAC4otBUTwBzANzbdDQ8fmnL1nQGM7J81YC%20UQ1t1QBO4Ons6MwY5WAW5GHk5eQA)

According to TS convention, you should use CamelCase for types and interfaces.

Also, `true | false` is just a `boolean`

Comment: Thanks! One problem is that there are many other properties not affected by Condition, so this way I have to write these twice and it's kinda redundant to me.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution

```
type Example<Condition extends boolean = false> = {
    b: string;
    c: string;
    e: string;
    f: string;
    g: string;
    h: string;
    i: string;
} & (Condition extends true ? {
    a: string;
} : {
    d: string;
})
```

anyway possible to do like this by using interfaces?

Comment: Yes, it is ok to do